# Version of Windows store application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps

I set version number for my Windows store application. but I found while I pack my application, it only allow me to input the version with 4 digit like 1.2.3.4, but in fact according to my practice requirement, I need to set the version with 5 digit like 1.2.3.4.5

May I know anything I can do to customize this?

Answer (score 2):

Versions number in Visual Studio have always been in a 4 digits format, with:

- 1st digit: version.Major,
- 2nd digit: version.Minor
- 3rd digit: version.Build
- 4th digit: version.Revision

See Version class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx

So you will have to use a workaround, your number cannot be stored in 5 digits